# knowing that a strong base is a strong electrolyte, when we add a weak acid in water, will its conjugate strong base be a strong electrolyte too?

Tags: acid-base, electrolysis

I am not sure if the questions makes sense. What i am trying to say is that, if weak acids form strong conjugate bases, why aren't they strong electrolytes?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Note that your question should ideally be posted in the body of your post. You can [edit] it in.

Comment: You know that basicity/acidity and conductivity are unrelated topics?

Comment: A strong acid is a strong electrolyte and a weak acid is a weak electrolyte no?

Comment: Not necessarily. Sulphuric acid is a very strong acid, but $96~\%\ \ce{H2SO4}$ is a lousy electrolyte.

Comment: that explains a lot. i mixed up some concepts thank you for your help.